# How to solve cannot access class com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I'm trying to run a project in my local machine then I encountered this error.

> "class org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor (in
> unnamed module @0x565b21bd) cannot access class
> com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl (in module java.sql.rowset) because
> module java.sql.rowset does not export com.sun.rowset to unnamed
> module"

I'm stock with this for days now. Please I need help. :(

I tried replacing the jar files, but no luck.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  What version(s) of Spring?

Comment: @StephenC My senior said that the web app was developed in java 8 , so I set my eclipse to java 8 also,, I'm not sure about the spring version, but I saw spring jar files in 3.04.
And I also have another web app that run this line of code 
" SqlRowSet rs = jdbctemplate.queryForRowSet(strSQL.toString(), parameters);"
but I was able to run this one on my local machine with no problem.

Comment: OK ... so you are currently >running< on a Java 9+ platform because the exception message talks about modules which is a Java 9 feature.  Indeed, the root problem is that that the Spring class (`SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor`) is trying to use internal JDK classes which is not allowed in later versions of Java.  I think that this was addressed in later releases of Spring.  You need to either >run< on Java 8, or upgrade to newer release of Spring that is compatible with your >runtime< Java platform.  Since Spring 3.x is past end-of-life, updating to Spring 5 or 6 is a better idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm running on Java 9,, but I set my jre to 1.8 in buildpath, I also changed the facets to 1.8, I also checked the compiler and it is set to 1.8. I also tried replacing the spring jar files to 4.3.1, it shows HTTP Status 404. I will try to replace the jar files to 5 and 6. I will update you on what will happen. Thank you so much @StephenC!

Comment: There in no doubt that you are >running< Java 9 or later.  You may well have multiple JVMs and/or JREs installed on the machine you are running on.  Note that the JRE on the build path is what it used to build your application ... not to run it.  (Perhaps you should get your senior developer to explain things to you ...)

Comment: Also ... randomly replacing Spring JAR files is a bad idea.  You should use proper dependency management in your builds. Assuming that your application is built using Maven or Gradle, the Spring "bill of materials" approach is best; see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom. Finally, you need to read the Spring documentation on which Spring versions are compatible with which Java versions.  Spring 4.x apparently does not run on Java 9 and later.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask my senior about the points you mentioned. I also checked the Java version installed on my machine; it says Java 8 Update 371 (build 1.8.0_371-b11).

What I'm really trying to do is import the project into Eclipse. I have another project with that same line of code, but that one runs without any problems.

And you are correct; I should start reading about the documentation for Java and Spring.

Comment: *"I also checked the Java version installed on my machine; it says Java 8 Update 371 (build 1.8.0_371-b11)."* - Not withstanding that, it is IMPOSSIBLE for you to get that exception when >running< the application using Java 8.  Java 8 does not support modules.  They were first introduced in Java 9.  So my guess is that you >also< have a later version of Java installed on your machine and that is being used when you run the application.  Or maybe you are deploying and running the application on a different machine.

Comment: If you don't understand what is going on, get your senior to help you out.  They can look at what you are doing and figure out how / why you are actually using a later version of Java to run the code.  It might be IDE configs, environment variables, wrapper scripts, running in a webapp container, in docker ... too many things for me to enumerate.

Comment: Finally, I've already figured it out. It has something to do with the Tomcat server configuration. The JRE version inside Tomcat is 17 (I don't know if I described it properly). What makes this complicated is that the other web app built using JRE 1.8 was running without any problems. The troubled web app is now running smoothly on my local machine. Thank you so much for all the hints you gave me. I hope you can give me some book recommendations about Java or authors to follow. Thank you so much @StephenC!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import javax.sql.rowset.*

CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet()
```

instead of

```
import com.sun.rowset.*

CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl()
```

Comment: so, I have to modify this?
org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.newCachedRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:78)

Comment: @AngeloOrale, I see your discussions. As Stephan said, there is version mismatch.

From the error log your provided, java 9+ platform is used since module feature start from java 9. But you are using Spring framework 3.0.4 (pretty old, released 10 years ago) which is compatible with java 6,7,8. 

I checked Spring framework 3.0.4's `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor` imports `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` directly. But this is impossible for java 9+ platform since `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` is not exported.

Comment: How will I know if I'm running Java 9? Because I'm setting my JRE to 1.8 in the build path. And how do I find out which Java version was used to create the web application? Thank you so much @NeveMore.

Comment: @AngeloOrale, try to find `pid` of your Spring application and then use command  `ps aux | grep pid` to check the java version

Comment: I already figured it out; it has to do with the Tomcat configuration. Thank you for commenting about the version mismatch about module features, like Stephen said.

I should start reading about Java releases to familiarize myself with version issues. Which version do you think I should start reading that still has significance in today's programming? or should I start reading from the very start?

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved the problem.

From java 8 is ok. Java 8 is old enough and actually it is still widely used in many projects. It won't be a long article for the new features released by each java version. So, let's read it.

Answer (score 0):

I've already figured it out. It has something to do with the Tomcat server configuration. The JRE version inside Tomcat is 17 (I don't know if I described it properly). StephenC and NeveMore is correct the error is about version mismatch. What makes this complicated is that the other web app I'm trying to import into Eclipse, which was built using JRE 1.8, was running without any problems.